# Want to check gmt date not from system but the original correct date

Tags: javascript

I want to get gmt date for my js file. so want to know how i can get date. i dont want get date from computer, i want correct gmt date using js file.

I want to know how i can do this?

Do i need to use jQuery or what.

I need to match date in my codes.

suppose:

**I have this codes from stack overflow**

```
var date = 11;
var month = 10;
var year = 2012

function Checkday() {
    if ( !isExpired() ) {
        start();
        } else {
        stop();
    };
};

function isExpired() {
    var current = new Date(); 
    current = current.getTime(); 
    var dateToCheck = new Date(); 
    dateToCheck.setFullYear(year); 
    dateToCheck.setMonth(month); 
    dateToCheck.setDate(date) 
    var checkdate = dateToCheck.getTime();
    return checkdate < current
}
```

This code checking date from system or we can say checking computer time and date. And i dont want that. because if we decrease time in computer time my js file will start working even if time is over.

Any solution.

With php its very easy but i cant use any php in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must have use any server side scripting language for get data & time otherwise no solution.You can also use php in ajax and get date & time

Comment: Yeah thanks AJAX is correct for this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a date instance from UTC values using [`Date.UTC`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.3):

```
var date  = 11;
var month = 10;
var year  = 2012

var utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(year, --month, date));
```

or if you have a UTC time value (milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z) you can give it to the Date constructor directly:

```
var dateObj = new Date(timeValue)
```

And read back UTC values using the [`getUTC*`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.11) methods.

As Harry said, to get an accurate time, you need to access some other resource, an AJAX request to your server may suit. In that case, don't bother with a client side date object, just send the expiry details and get the sever to work it out and send a simple yes/no or true/false reply.